# Is there a way of using a function on a list of files?

Tags: function, file, path

I am trying to use a function for "cleaning" up the data a bit but I want to use it on multiple dataset from different files.

So far I have tried to make a list of files to use the function on. I made the list using the this:

```
files = "/data1.txt /data2.txt"
file_list = list(files.split(" "))
```

The function I'm trying to use:

```
def clean_data(file):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, sep= "\n|\\t", decimal ='.', names=['nM','I'], engine='python', header=None)
    df = pd.DataFrame(df)
    data_start = int(df.loc[df['nM'].str.startswith('#DATA')].index[0] + 1)
    df = df[int(data_start):]
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    return df
```

However when I try to use the function on the list such as:

clean_data(file_list)

I produce the error message:

```
 Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>
```

It there a way to resolve this issue or would it be best to take a different approach to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Using argparse and a for loop i got around the error. There I properly a better way to do this but for now it works.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='x.py')
parser.add_argument('--i', help='input txt files', nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args("--I /data1.txt /data2.txt" .split())

for file in args.i:
clean_data(file)
```